# Adding a time loop to fill in an array in a Python function

Tags: python

I am trying to plot projectile motion for 3 different integration methods which fill fill an array giving the x-coordinates of the object at a consistently increasing timestamp. I have the function done, and it is working to compute the values, but I can only get it to either give the x-coordinate at the first timestamp, or a repeat of this coordinate, but over all the timestamps. I was having an issue denoting the relationship between the elements of the array, which I though I fixed but now am getting an error saying that the axes lengths are not correct. I mainly need help figuring out how to make the function loop over each timestamp to fill in the array. Here is the code I have so far:

```
def projectile_motion(v0, theta, tau, method, air_resistance=True):

    # Convert launch angle to radians
    theta = math.radians(theta)

    # Initial conditions
    x = [np.empty((1,100))]
    y = h0
    vx = v0 * math.cos(theta)
    vy = v0 * math.sin(theta)

    for i in range(len(x)):#filling in array
        j=i+1
        x[j]=x[i]+x[i]*tau

    # Integration method
    if method == 'Euler':
        def update():
            nonlocal x, y, vx, vy
            if air_resistance:
                v = math.sqrt(vx**2 + vy**2)
                ax = -(Cd*rho*A*v*vx)/(2*m)
                ay = -g - (Cd*rho*A*v*vy)/(2*m)
                vx += ax * tau
                vy += ay * tau
            else:
                vy -= g * tau
            x += vx * tau
            y += vy * tau
    elif method == 'Euler-Cromer':
        def update():
            nonlocal x, y, vx, vy
            if air_resistance:
                v = math.sqrt(vx**2 + vy**2)
                ax = -(Cd*rho*A*v*vx)/(2*m)
                ay = -g - (Cd*rho*A*v*vy)/(2*m)
                vx += ax * tau
                vy += ay * tau
            else:
                vy -= g * tau
            x += vx * tau
            y += vy * tau
            if y < 0:
                vy = -vy
    elif method == 'Midpoint':
        def update():
            nonlocal x, y, vx, vy
            if air_resistance:
                v = math.sqrt(vx**2 + vy**2)
                ax = -(Cd*rho*A*v*vx)/(2*m)
                ay = -g - (Cd*rho*A*v*vy)/(2*m)
                vx_half = vx + ax * tau/2
                vy_half = vy + ay * tau/2
                v_half = math.sqrt(vx_half**2 + vy_half**2)
                ax_half = -(Cd*rho*A*v_half*vx_half)/(2*m)
                ay_half = -g - (Cd*rho*A*v_half*vy_half)/(2*m)
                vx += ax_half * tau
                vy += ay_half * tau
            else:
                vy -= g * tau
            x += vx * tau
            y += vy * tau
            if y < 0:
                 vy = -vy

    # Time loop
    while y >= 0:
        update()

    return x
```

I mainly need help figuring out how to make the function loop over each timestamp to fill in the array. The ultimate goal is to be able to plot the three different conditions to compare them.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. SO is a Q&A site, but you haven't asked a question, and it's not clear what exactly you need help with. Like, for example, do you know why your current loop is not working? Not that I do, but that's the kind of thing you should think about when starting debugging. Please read [ask].

Comment: **More info**: For debugging help, you'd need to make a [mre] including complete but minimal code (since, to start, `h0` and `g` are not defined, and I assume the three different `method`s are redundant for this problem). And see also: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/4518341) Lastly, you should add the tags for any libraries your question's about, like probably [tag:numpy].

Answer (score 1):

Starting at a high level:

1. Try not to use the "nonlocal" keyword.  It adds code complexity and makes debugging more difficult.  Pass everything your function needs as arguments.
2. Define your update functions as separate python functions.  Setting the update function differently depending on scope is prone to error.

Your example code is not runnable without a number of non-local variables set.
Following your code intention, I made an example that uses numpy functionality.

With a similar pattern you could add more complex "state update" functions.

```
import math
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# update equation
def update_function1(position, velocity, acceleration, timestep=.1, drag=.98):
    position = position + velocity * timestep
    velocity = velocity + acceleration * timestep
    acceleration = acceleration * drag
    return position, velocity, acceleration
    
def projectile_motion_simple(theta, velocity, update_function, timestep=0.1, gravity=9.81):
    """quantized integration method"""
    
    theta = theta * np.pi / 180
    
    # initial conditions
    p = np.array([0, 0], dtype=np.float64)
    v = velocity * np.array([np.cos(theta), np.sin(theta)])
    a = np.array([0, -gravity])
    
    simulation_duration = 2
    
    data = []
    time = np.arange(0, simulation_duration, timestep)
    for t in time:
        p, v, a = update_function(p, v, a, timestep)
        data.append((p, v, a))
    data = np.array(data)
    
    return time, data
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    from functools import partial
    
    time, data = projectile_motion_simple(45, 10, partial(update_function1, drag=.98))
    plt.title("Plot of X, Y positions")
    plt.plot(time, data[:, 0, 1], time, data[:, 0, 0])
    # plt.title("Plot of X, Y Velocity")
    # plt.plot(time, data[:, 1, 1], time, data[:, 1, 0])
    plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: it could also be a good idea to wrap the whole thing in a class, then updating variables would be pretty straight forward